# О логировании в java

Tags: java, логирование

Приводится на хабре в статье библиотека *Apache Commons Logging* (не знаю смысл этой библиотеки,  не юзал) и комментарий:

> За `System.out.println` для вывода логов начинающим программистам уже через неделю обучения следует отрубать руки.

Так вот вопрос: а почему `print` настолько плох?

P.S. Сам я основы языка очень плохо знаю.

Comment: подумай о проекте с миллионом строк кода, и об удобстве использования принта, его возможностях включения/настройки/способах логирования, особенно, в уже скомпилированном коде

Comment: я думал) просто логи тоже надо так же вручную писать, как и принт ) я исходил из этого и из того, что можно сделать библиотеку основанную на логировании с помощью принта и направлять сообщения в сторонний файл , но когда речь идет о о том чтобы делать записи в сторонний файл , это уже называют не Принт , а логированием)) разница в общем этом нюансе. А я думал может принт более ресурсозатратнее .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Логирование - это все-таки больше, чем вывод строк в консоль. Здесь имеют место следующие параметры:

- Цель: это может быть консоль (stdout), немного другая консоль (stderr), файл, удаленный сервер сбора логов
- Уровень логирования: для разных выводов может быть разный уровень вывода: например, в один файл мы скидываем всё, но храним только последние десять мегабайт, а в другой отправляем только сообщения уровня WARN и выше, но храним историю за последние шесть месяцев
- Per-package настройки: в случае, если "шалит" конкретный участок кода, можно включить логирование только для него
- Ротация логов: логи чаще всего надо хранить в файлах, которые нужно периодически подчищать, и при этом во время проведения работ продолжать писать логи
- Контекст выполнения: зачастую просто сообщения недостаточно (если транзакция провалилась, то какие входные параметры этому поспособтсвовали?), поэтому существуют штуки типа MDC, чтобы при обработке конкретного юзера перед каждым вашим сообщением добавлялась мапа `{processed user id: 12345}`
- Подстановка параметров: писать `Logger.debug("Transaction #{} has failed with message '{}'", transaction.getId(), e.getMessage())` гораздо удобнее, чем писать `System.out.ptintln("Transaction #" + transaction.getId() + " has failed with message '" + e.getMessage() + "'")`. Кроме удобства, это позволяет не конкатенировать строки, если уровень логирования выше самого сообщения (т.е. при уровне INFO сообщения с уровнем DEBUG не будут тратить ресурсы на конкатенацию) и группировать лог-сообщения по шаблону (искать в логах вместо просто слова "transaction" конкретный шаблон).

Всем этим занимается библиотека логирования, и она сильно упрощает жизнь, когда нужно перейти от одной модели к другой, например, когда логи возле приложения хранить стало нецелесообразно, для переключения на удаленный сервер достаточно подключить новый аппендер и перезапустить приложение. Кроме того, существует ситуация, когда логов настолько много, что I/O не успевает справляться - о проблемах такого рода, как правило, не думают вплоть до их появления, а в библиотеках (я надеюсь) некоторые предусмотрительные шаги уже сделаны (например, logback совершенно точно по умолчанию пытается добавить сообщение пять раз на тот случай, если что-то пошло не так).

Comment: Логирование задедлочилось - это классный случай)))

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде про concurrency ни слова не было

Comment: Это я просто вспомнил. Приложение переставало работать из-за того, что логгирование как-то дедлочилось не поделив доступ к файлу.

Comment: А еще проект почти всегда использует сторонние библиотеки. И если они начнут писать в `System.out`, когда им вздумается, никто не обрадуется.

Answer (score 3):

По сути, выше уже всё было сказано, добавлю ещё один практический аспект. Консоль имеет определённую емкость. И, например, если она равна 300 строк, то в случае, если в неё запишутся 500 строк, начальные 200 строк вы уже не увидите. Можно, конечно, увеличить размер буфера консоли, но тогда придётся его увеличивать постоянно, а это не лучший вариант. Особенно для большого проекта, где логи записываются практически непрерывно, и логируется большой объём данных.